# bash : Bad Substitution on array variable

Tags: bash, shell

Below is my extract of the failure part:

```
if [[ -n "${war_to_be_deployed-}" ]] ; then
    [[ "${#runtime_args[@]-}" == "${#expected_runtime_args[@]-}" ]]             || _fatal "Failed runtime_args"     
    for ((i=0 ; i<${#runtime_args[@]-} ; ++i)); do
```

throws below error on bash `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. What is it that I'm doing incorrect here ? thank you.

`${#runtime_args[@]-}: bad substitution`

Comment: Why is there a `-` in `${#runtime_args[@]-}` and `${#expected_runtime_args[@]-}`? It is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${#runtime_args[@]}` is number of elements in the array.  The trialing `-` is what triggers the error.  Is this script generated?  It looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: No, its not generated, it runs fine on previous Ubuntu version, version being Ubuntu 14